# SQL Server Reporting Services export to another server

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

Is there anyway to transfer SQL Server Reporting Services reports to another server ?

Are reports stored in the Reporting Service database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can redeploy them from your solution in BIDS just point them at the new server.
You will not have any subscriptions carried over though.

On the server the reports are stored in the Catalog table.

If for some reason you don't want to redploy you can transfer like this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156421(SQL.90).aspx